# Video tag не работает в Safari

Tags: html, css, html5, видео, safari

Вот собственно сам код:

```
<div class="mbYTP_wrapper" id="wrapper_mbYTP_bgndVideo" style="position: fixed; z-index: 0; min-width: 100%;height:100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; transform: translateZ(0px); backface-visibility: hidden;"><video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" class="headervid" id="mbYTP_bgndVideo" class="playerBox"><source src="https://kinoprokat.com/templates/shema/site01.mp4" type="video/mp4"><p>Your browser doesn support video</p></video><div class="YTPOverlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height:100%"></div></div>
```

Не работает в Safari.

Comment: у меня и код и отдельно мувик в сафари играет...

Comment: а `video` и не работает в сафари, черный квадрат отображается, не поддерживается

Comment: @HamSter с чего это? video это html5 тег. Все работает.